# maven compiler UTF 8 error when changing to executable

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am experimenting with using an executable for the maven compiler plugin instead of the basic declaring source/target. I am running into an issue with the encoding when I do this and am curious why it is happening. I know that setting the encoding to cp1252 fixes the issue when using an executable, but can't figure out why utf-8 is fine when not using an executable.

Executable:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac</executable>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration> 
        </plugin>
```

Note: D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 is also my JAVA_HOME in the env

Breaks compilation for both maven compiler versions 3.1 and 3.5.1:

```
[ERROR] D:\Projects\testproject\src\main\java\com\test\service\TestService.java:
[467,70] error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

Orig:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Still compiles successfully either way, but this is in the logs:
maven compiler plugin version: 3.5.1

```
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/testproject/src/main/java/com/test/service/TestService.java
[467,85] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

maven compiler plugin version: 3.1

```
[WARNING] /D:/Projects/testproject/src/main/java/com/test/service/TestService.java
[467,85] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

The args passed from both logs: -g -nowarn -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8.

I noticed on the maven compiler plugin home page:

> The Compiler Plugin
>   is used to compile the sources of your project. Since 3.0, the default
>   compiler is javax.tools.JavaCompiler (if you are using java 1.6) and
>   is used to compile Java sources. If you want to force the plugin using
>   javac, you must configure the plugin option forceJavacCompilerUse.

Is there a way to make the executable use the same instead of javac if that is causing the issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the full pom file and the source of the java file that fail to compile?